# accidently overwritten the ~/.bashrc file

Tags: files, backup, bashrc

while testing some commands I cleared the content of the `~/.bashrc`  file
and i don't have a backup from it

is it enough to copy from `/etc/skel/.bashrc` to login normally the next time or i may face some problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you haven't made any significant modifications, copying the skeleton bashrc is enough. It doesn't affect the boot or GUI login process.